# how can I make a back button?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a classlist:

```
const answers = document.querySelectorAll('.answer')
```

and the next button using forEach:

```
nextButton.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
   nextAnswer();
}
const nextAnswer = () => {
    answers.forEach( function(el) {
        if (!el.classList.contains('hidden')) {
          el.classList.add('hidden')
          console.log(el)
        }
    })
    answers[currAnswer].classList.remove('hidden')
    currAnswer++
    if(currAnswer == 7) {
       nextButton.innerHTML = "Send"
       nextButton.className = "submit_button"

    }
}
```

here is the html:

```
<div class="answer question_one hidden">
    <div class="pictures">
        <div data-id="0" id="picture" class="picture">
            <img src="C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\kviz\\Photo\\Question1\\i.jpg" width=250px height=250px>
        </div>
        <div data-id="1" id="picture" class="picture">
            <img src="C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\kviz\\Photo\\Question1\\i1.jpg" width=250px height=250px>
        </div>
        <div data-id="2" id="picture" class="picture">
            <img src="C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\kviz\\Photo\\Question1\\i2.jpg" width=250px height=250px>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="answer question_three hidden">
    <input type="text" class="address_input" placeholder="Введите адрес">
    <div class="inline"></div>
</div>
<div class="answer question_four hidden">
    <div class="f_main">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-checkbox" id="0" name="happy" value="yes">
        <label for="0">5</label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-checkbox" id="1" name="happy" value="yes">
        <label for="1">30</label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-checkbox" id="2" name="happy" value="yes">
        <label for="2">60</label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-checkbox" id="3" name="happy" value="yes">
        <label for="3">80</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

how can I make a back button ?
I tried to implement it but couldn't
"He asks for clarification but I do not know what to add"

Comment: Please add snippet with html for better understanding.

Comment: Could you explain what your code is supposed to do, and maybe send your html code?

Comment: look : classic!  if save ex1.html <!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="UTF-8"></head><body><a href="ex2.html">fist navigate to ex2.html</a></body></html>   then  ex2.html :  <!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="UTF-8"></head><body><script>back=function(){history.back();}</script><input type="button" value="back" onclick="back();"></body></html> run ex1.html and click the button

Answer (score 1):

If you're not using a UI framework (e.g. React) and just going with plain JS, I'd handle it this way (with a dedicated function for reconciling the UI state):

> Also note that I'm using a dedicated button for each action (and hiding/disabling them as appropriate), rather than reusing buttons.

```js
let currAnswer = 0;

const answers = document.querySelectorAll('.answer');
const btnPrev = document.querySelector('button.button_previous');
const btnNext = document.querySelector('button.button_next');
const btnSubmit = document.querySelector('button.button_submit');

btnPrev.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (currAnswer > 0) currAnswer -= 1;
  updateUI();
});

btnNext.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (currAnswer < answers.length) currAnswer += 1;
  updateUI();
});

function updateUI () {
  for (const elm of answers) elm.classList.add('hidden');
  answers[currAnswer]?.classList.remove('hidden');

  btnPrev.disabled = currAnswer === 0;

  if (currAnswer === answers.length) {
    btnNext.classList.add('hidden');
    btnSubmit.classList.remove('hidden');
  }
  else {
    btnNext.classList.remove('hidden');
    btnSubmit.classList.add('hidden');
  }
}

// Initialize the UI state
updateUI();
```

```css
.hidden { display: none; }
```

```html
<div class="answer hidden">answer 1</div>
<div class="answer hidden">answer 2</div>
<div class="answer hidden">answer 3</div>
<div class="answer hidden">answer 4</div>
<div class="answer hidden">answer 5</div>
<div class="answer hidden">answer 6</div>
<div class="answer hidden">answer 7</div>

<div>
  <button class="button_previous">previous</button>
  <button class="button_next">next</button>
  <button class="button_submit hidden">send</button>
</div>
```